# Apache External Redirect 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am struggling to do a simple external redirect (a rewrite really, I don't want to send the user a 3xx response) from one machine to another for web traffic.

The following rule should transparently proxy requests from http://myserver.com/api/users/1 to http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1 but instead, I only get 404 Not Found responses from Apache.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   "^/api(.*)" "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/$1" [R]
```

Comment: proxying the request is my desired result. If this isn't how to do it, please leave an answer pointing me in the right direction

Comment: You need to have control over apache config to enable `mod_proxy`

Comment: I have complete control over the config/server. I'll take a look at `mod_proxy`. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to have control over apache config to enable `mod_proxy`
2. Remove `R` flag and use `P` for proxy.

Your rule will be:

```
RewriteRule ^/?api(.*)$ http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/$1 [P,L,NC]
```

Comment: lifesaver. Thank you!